# eloquent morphmany relationship - update and/or save

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have seen the similar Q asked here but did not find any suitable answer and hence asking again. If you know any thread please guide me to it,

I have

Model User and Model Property and both have Address

```
class Address {
    protected $fillable = ['address','city','state','zip'];

  public function addressable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}//Address

class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['first_name','last_name', 'title'];

  public function address(){
        return $this->morphMany('Address', 'addressable');
    }
}//User

class Property extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['name','code'];

  public function address(){
        return $this->morphMany('Address', 'addressable');
    }
}//Property
```

Is there any way to UpdateIfNotCreate type method for address to update as well associate with User/Property?

Taylor Otwell's official answer,

```
$account = Account::find(99);
User::find(1)->account()->associate($account)->save();
```

is NOT working as I am getting an exception

message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()"
type: "BadMethodCallException"

The way I have solved the issue is as follows:

```
$data = Input::all();

if($data['id'] > 0){
    $address_id = $data['id']; unset($data['id']);
    $address = Address::find($address_id)->update($data);
}//existing
else{
    $address = new Address($data);
    User::find($user_id)->address()->save($address);
}//add new
```

I could use the different Routes ( PUT to /update{id} and  POST to / ) 
but in my case both new and existing records are coming to same route ( /update )

Can you guys please recommend the better way to go about this?

Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```php
// get only applicable fields
$input = Input::only('address','city','state','zip');

// get existing or instantiate new address
$address = Address::firstOrNew($input);

// associate the address with the user
// btw I would rather call this relation addresses if it's morhpmany
User::find($userId)->addresses()->save($address);
```

---

Not sure where you got Taylor's answer, but I don't think it was supposed for this case. It couldn't work anyway.

Comment: First of all, Thx for the answer. I have a Q, in firstOrNew how will it find out if we are not passing id of address (specially for existing one)? In this case, id of the address is in the post field. Any thoughts? Thx

Comment: This is the way to ommit the `id`. Eloquent will find existing `Address` by the `address,city,state,zip` combination (address is more or less a value object, id doesn't matter at all in the end) or instantiate new model and fill the above combo as its attributes. Try this first.

Comment: Thx again. What happens if user edits the address? Seems like it will insert a new row which is certainly not a desirable outcome. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, like I said, address is pretty much value object, so it shouldn't be changed in my opinion. Anyway, if you want to edit, simply pass `id` and update fetched row. And when you create new, just create - single responsibility.